# TypeError: Cannot set property 'frozenRowCount' of undefined (line 6, file "Header-Row-Frozen")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

basically what i'm tring to do is: use the frozenRowCount property to freeze the first row of a sheet. But when the code executes all i get is "TypeError: Cannot set property 'frozenRowCount' of undefined (line 6, file "Header-Row-Frozen")". When the frozenRowCount property is instanciated the code just doesn't reach it. This is the code:

```
function headerFunction() {
  //Change the sheet's first header
   var updateSheetPropertiesRequest = Sheets.newUpdateSheetPropertiesRequest();
  updateSheetPropertiesRequest.properties = Sheets.newSheetProperties();
  updateSheetPropertiesRequest.properties.sheetId.gridProperties.frozenRowCount = 1;
  updateSheetPropertiesRequest.fields = 'gridProperties.frozenRowCount';

  // Set the request   
  var requests = Sheets.newRequest();
  requests.updateSheetProperties = updateSheetPropertiesRequest;

  // Set request to Spreadsheet
  var batchUpdateRequest = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
  batchUpdateRequest.requests = requests;

  // Add additional requests (operations)
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchUpdateRequest, spreadsheetId);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to freeze the 1st row of a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API of Advanced Google services with Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `updateSheetPropertiesRequest.properties.sheetId.gridProperties.frozenRowCount = 1;` is not correct. `sheetId` is the integer type. So please set the sheet ID here.
- In order to create an object of `gridProperties`, please use `newGridProperties()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Fom:

```
var updateSheetPropertiesRequest = Sheets.newUpdateSheetPropertiesRequest();
updateSheetPropertiesRequest.properties = Sheets.newSheetProperties();
updateSheetPropertiesRequest.properties.sheetId.gridProperties.frozenRowCount = 1;
updateSheetPropertiesRequest.fields = 'gridProperties.frozenRowCount';
```

To:

```
var updateSheetPropertiesRequest = Sheets.newUpdateSheetPropertiesRequest();
updateSheetPropertiesRequest.properties = Sheets.newSheetProperties();
updateSheetPropertiesRequest.properties.sheetId = sheetId;  // Modified
var gridProperties = Sheets.newGridProperties();  // Added
gridProperties.frozenRowCount = 1;  // Added
updateSheetPropertiesRequest.properties.gridProperties = gridProperties;  // Added
updateSheetPropertiesRequest.fields = 'gridProperties.frozenRowCount';
```

- Please set `sheetId`. In this case, the sheet ID is the sheet ID of the sheet you want to reflect this request body.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that Sheets API have already been enabled at Advanced Google services.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)